# create extention method for FormControl in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i want to create a extention for formGroup to convert persian date to gorgian date .

this my code for extention :

```
   import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms'

export { }

declare global {
    interface FormControl {
        ToMiladidate(date: Date): string;
    }
}

FormControl.prototype.ToMiladidate = function (date: Date): string {
    if (!date)
        return this;
    return new Date(date).toISOString();
}
```

but in this line it show me error :

```
FormControl.prototype.ToMiladidate
```

show me this error :

> Property 'ToMiladidate' does not exist on type 'FormControl'

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ???**

Answer (score 2):

If this question is still relevant, here is the answer:

```
declare module '@angular/forms' {


interface AbstractControl {
    ToMiladidate(date: Date): string;
  }
}

AbstractControl.prototype.ToMiladidate = function (date: Date): string {
  if (!date)
    return this;
  return new Date(date).toISOString();
}
```

The solution is to use AbstractFormControl instead of FormControl and declare not global module but **@angular/forms**. And if you have declared prototype in a separate file when you need to import your prototype into **app.module.ts** at the top of imports:

```
import './form.prototype';
```

Comment: This is what I looking for. Thanks, I really appreciate it.